# How do I convert TIFF files to BIL files with header?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

In my project, I have hundreds of GeoTIFF files that needed to be converted to .bil files with .hdr (header). They are satellite rainfall data. Can anyone help with a quick method?

Comment: Perhaps opposite to this https://community.esri.com/thread/57843. Do you mean this format as output https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/ehdr.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 import gdal 
 input = r"D:\ESCUELA\ hh.tif"
 out =  "D:\ESCUELA\ prueba.bil"

 gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab = input,
            destNameOrDestDS=out ,
            format= 'EHdr',
            dstSRS= 'EPSG:3795')
```

just add a loop for all the files in your path

```
   import gdal
   import os

   path = r'D:\ESCUELA\imgSat8'
   out = 'D:\ESCUELA\prueba'
   bandList = [band for band in os.listdir(path) if band[-4:]=='.TIF']
   iter =range(len(bandList))

   for i in iter:
         gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab = path + '\\'+ bandList[i],
          destNameOrDestDS=out+'\\'+bandList[i][:-4]+'.bil',
          format = 'EHdr',
          dstSRS='EPSG:3795')
```